# Aggregated sum month by month until variable changed

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I´m working with invoices. I want to calculate the pool of money claimable each month (invoice´s amount once it past expiration date). The point is that the invoices can be canceled and paid. So, I would like to aggregate the value of the invoices, month by month, taking into account only invoices from month corresponding the day after the expiration date until the month it has been paid or canceled, including that month.

Here is an example of my matrix

```
   Client.Code.     Invoice  Expiration.Date    Amount Payment.date Out.Of.Process
1:      1004773 21506000409      2016-09-28   6993.80         <NA>        Current
2:      1004773 21506000670      2016-08-29  30034.62         <NA>        Current
3:      1004773 21507000583      2017-10-29   3872.00         <NA>        Current
4:      1005109 21601000237      2016-04-30   3594.31         <NA>        Current
5:      1005109 21606000480      2016-08-29   6301.68         <NA>        Current
6:      1004737 20170500125      2016-07-24 142818.72   2017-06-19           Paid
```

For example, the code should count the first one from September in each aggregate and should count the number six from July 16 to June 17 in every aggregate. The number 4 would be better to count in each month from may 16 (next day).

There is a way to achieve the aggregate sum of amount invoices claimable per month I´m looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution which aggregates Amount by month. I don't know if it is exactly what you wanted, but its close I hope.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate) # to floor_date function
your_df %>% mutate(exp_date = as.Date(expiration.Date), #you might not need this if you expiration date is in Date format
monthly_date = floor_date(exp_date, "month")) %>%
select(Amount,monthly_date) %>%
group_by(monthly_date) %>%
summarise(aggregate_amt = sum(Amount))
```

Comment: Not really, It just aggregate the amount of the invoices per month of expiration.